# Hide checkout button until shipping option is chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using simpleCart js. I would like to have the checkout button and shipping cost hidden until the customer selects UK or Rest of World. Here is the select block:

```
<select id="shippingSelect" onchange="simpleCart.update();">
 <option value="nothing" selected="selected">Choose Shipping Location</option>
 <option value="uk">UK</option>
 <option value="world">Rest of World</option>
</select>
```

Under that is the shipping cost and checkout button:

```
<div class="place_order" style="display:none">
 <span id="simpleCart_shipping" class="simpleCart_shipping"></span>
 <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout btnDownload">checkout</a>
</div>
```

The simpleCart script that generates the cart:

```
<script>
simpleCart({
    cartColumns: [
        { attr: "name" , label: "Item" },
        { view: "decrement" , label: false , text: "-" },
        { attr: "quantity", label: "Quantity", view: "input"},
        { view: "increment" , label: false , text: "+" },
        { attr: "price", label: "Price"},
        { attr: "total" , label: "Subtotal", view: "currency"  }
    ],
    cartStyle: "table",
    currency: "GBP",
    language: "english-us",
    checkout: { 
        type: "PayPal" , 
        email: "email@ddress",
        success: "success.html"
    },
    shippingCustom: function(){ 
                 if( $("#shippingSelect").val() == "uk" ){
                      return 0;
                 } else {
                      return 2;
             }
        }
    });


</script>
```

I thought I could use `$('.place_order').css('display', 'inline');` to change the inline style but I don't know how to do it, whether to incorporate it into the simpleCart script or have it trigger a separate script? Perhaps there is a more efficient way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
$('.simpleCart_checkout btnDownload').hide(); //hide your element upon intial page load

$('#shippingselect').change(function() {
   if ($(this).val() != "nothing") {
      $('.simpleCart_checkout btnDownload').show(); //show element if shipping option selected
   } else {
      $('.simpleCart_checkout btnDownload').hide();
   }
});
```

AFAIK it is bad practice to have spaces in class/id names.

It would be better in my opinion to disable/enable the button instead of hiding or showing it.

```
$('.simpleCart_checkout btnDownload').attr('disabled', true);
```